# Adding code to header tag

Tags: header, tags

i have no access to the index.html file and i want to add this piece of code inside the  tag so IE8 will display elements that are not currently displaying:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js">        </script>
<![endif]-->
```

Is there a way for me to insert this line of code without going into the index.html file which i dont have access to? The easiest way.

Thank yuo

Answer (score 0):

What tag are you trying to display it in? the header tags? It's not optimal to add a second set of  tags but you can.

Comment: well it was suggested i add the script above inside the header tags.